# Homework: no subquery in getting a value indirectly

Tags: sql

I'm having a hard time creating a query for smth that sounds like this: 
what is the name and color of the items that cost more than grey box detergent(2 attributes: color:grey, type:detergent).

NOTE: I'm NOT allowed to user subqueries or use the price as a constant.

using subqueries I managed to get this:

```
SELECT name, color
FROM items
WHERE cost > (SELECT price FROM items WHERE type='detergent' AND color='grey');
```

any ideas on how can I get the above query without using a subquery?

I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: I'll bet your TA or professor might have some ideas, and would welcome the question.

Comment: not necessarily, he just wants the results, but spent almost an hour thinking on how to solve this and ended up having a 5line query

Comment: And I didn't even notice this was a homework question... they should make the homework tag red and twice as large to make it easier to see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a join to self.

```
SELECT i1.name, i1.color
FROM items i1
INNER JOIN items i2 
  ON (i2.type = 'detergent' 
     AND i2.color = 'grey' 
     AND i1.cost > i2.cost)
```

Comment: Don;t know if OPs scenario allows this, but this solution will include results from all higher price grey detergent records if there is more than one grey detergent.

Comment: well, the questions specifies that we're not supposed to use price as a  constant or subqueries. I came over this solution before, but thought that cost shouldn't be used.

Comment: Actually, what is the difference between cost and price? It seems they got lumped into one in my mind.

Comment: oh, yeah. they are the same(my view of the query was initially with price)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, color 
FROM items t1
join (SELECT price FROM items WHERE type='detergent' AND color='grey') t2
on t1.price > t2.price;

Answer (score -1):

This way:

```
SELECT distinct others.name, others.color
FROM items others
   Join items GreyDet
       On others.Price > greyDet.Price
WHERE others.type <> 'detergent'
    And others.Color <> 'grey'
    And greyDet.type = 'detergent'
    And greyDet.Color = 'grey';
```

NOTE: This solution restricts output to only rows that are not grey detergents. This is necessary if it is possible to have more than one grey detergent record, with different prices..